# Access SVG DOM when using ASV plugin in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, firefox-addon

I have to develop for Firefox using the Adobe SVG Plugin 6. When using Firefox's native SVG viewing capabilities, I can simply look at `document.documentElement`, which will give me the root `svg` element and from there I can navigate the DOM to where I want.

With the ASV in Firefox, it appears to make a skeleton HTML file with an `embed` in it, and I can't get past that. There don't seem to be any properties or methods from the `embed` that lead to the SVG document.

Supposedly there is a `window.svgDocument` property created by the plugin, but I can't get that to work (maybe it's IE only).

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I do not believe this is possible.

After investigation I found that `document.embeds[0].getSVGDocument()` works with Firefox native SVG, and with IE using ASV, but *not* Firefox with ASV. There does not seem to be a way of accessing the SVG document of an SVG from outside the SVG when using Firefox and ASV.

This project has been abandoned and instead we will be displaying everything outside the SVG. But if someone knows a way, I would still be interested.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [svgweb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/) which adds SVG support to all browsers that don't have native support by using Flash Player.